# Is there an "Adventure Path" analog for White Wolf games?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, world-of-darkness, adventure-path, chronicles-of-darkness

I love the [Pathfinder Adventure Path](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Adventure_Path) system. It offloads tons of game master work and provides a fully coherent campaign for months of play.

White Wolf's [Storytelling Adventure System](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Storytelling_Adventure_System) (SAS) is great, but appears to involve mostly one-off modules rather than continuous plot and advancement.

Does White Wolf, or any third party, provide (or have planned) something like the AP system for any of its games, classic or modern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite. There have been capsule adventures — like *Diablerie: Britain* and *Diablerie: Mexico.* There have been linked adventures, like *Chaos Factor* and *Loom of Fate*. And one can't forget the *Giovanni Chronicles* series, which is most like an Adventure Path in that it takes player characters from "neonate" to "elder" levels as they progress in time.

However, up to this point, there has been nothing that's as player-focused and well-tested as a Pathfinder Adventure Path, one that's playable basically out of the box and suitable for the "typical" coterie of supernatural characters. However, the new *Fall of London* and *Contagion Chronicle* books for *Vampire 5th Edition* and *Chronicles of Darkness* may suit your needs when they come out.